# How to find all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z} / 30 \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

$$
\text { Find all the ideals of } \mathbb{Z} / 30 \mathbb{Z} \text {. }
$$

How does one quickly find all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z} / 30 \mathbb{Z}$?
I know this is a principal ideal ring so we can test each element individually, but is there an easy way to tell when two elements generate the same ideal?

Comment: Quickly? The ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are the $d\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $d\mid n$. It is rather quick to find the divisors of $30$.

Comment: In general, if you have a ring $R$ and an ideal $\mathfrak{i}\triangleleft R$, the ideals, maximal ideals and prime ideals of the factor ring $R/\mathfrak{i}$ are basically those of $R$ that contain $\mathfrak{i}$.